# What is the big o estimate of this nested for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, big-o, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out what the big o estimate of the following nested for loop is.

```
for(int i = 10; i to 100; i++){
 for(int j = 1; j to i; j++){
  for(int k = 1; k to j; k++){
   s=s+i+j;
  }
 }
}
```

I was thinking that the two inner loops run n times but I am unsure about the first loop.

What would the Big O estimate be for this code?

Comment: O(1) because the outer loop is bound by a constant

Comment: If you're *trying* to figure it out, you've made some attempts.  What do you know?  What parts are you confused about?

Comment: It isn't valid code. If it was valid, it would be constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically the complexity is `O(1)` because `100` is a constant and thus the number of operations is always the same. If the author assumed that `100` is a parameter and can be some variable, i.e.

```
int n = 100; //or read it somewhere
for (int i = 10; i < n; ++i) {
    .... 
}
```

then the complexity is `O(n^3)`. The first cycle body is executed `n - 10` times which is `O(n)`, the second cycle's body is executed from `n - 10` times to once, which is again `O(n)`, and the same can be stated for the innermost cycle, thus giving us `O(n^3)`.

Article useful for understanding the big O notation: [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1):

the complexity is `O(1)` since there is no `n` here and the number of ops can be calculated exactly

Comment: You posted a wrong answer then changed the answer to what user @Joni posted.

Comment: i dont see answer from a joni here. i changed to post the right answer